# m3u8 URL scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, network-programming

I am trying to find the request URL of a m3u8 file programmatically, without using the Browser network tab.
With the python code down here I still can't get the request URL of the m3u8 file.
[Screenshot of the request URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoQQL.png)

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright 
     
    url = "https://example.com" 
     
    with sync_playwright() as p: 
        browser = p.chromium.launch() 
        page = browser.new_page() 
     
        page.on("response", lambda response: print( 
            "<<", response.status, response.url)) 
        page.goto(url, wait_until="networkidle", timeout=90000) 
     
        print(page.content()) 
     
        page.context.close() 
        browser.close()
```

my question therefore is: what am I missing that I am not able to access the m3u8 URL?

Comment: That's a photo, not an m3u8 file.

Comment: I know but the principle is the same. What I need to access is the URL request